# Array method doesn't work in partial view

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-5

Rails5, none of the array methods are working in a partial view. If the recipient column is an array:

```
<%= @mail.recipients.first %>
```

Brings up:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `first' for nil:NilClass):
```

It works fine if I do a binding.pry before it and do the same thing in the console.   However, if I do:

```
<%= @mail.recipients %>
```

It gives me the full array.   Just wondering if array methods are not accessible in views?

---

EDIT:

```
<%= @mail %>
```

gives me

```
#<Mail::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f3658bf4f38>
```

then i put it through

```
<% @mail.each do |mail| %>
```

and inside that i do

```
<%= mail %>
```

it gives me

```
<Mail:0x007f3668951618>
```

then i do

```
<%= mail.recipients.class %>
```

it gives me

```
Array
```

then i do

```
<%= mail.recipients.first %>
```

it gives me

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `first' for nil:NilClass):
```

Comment: You already should know what is the problem, you are trying to call `first` method on a `nil` object. To get rid of this error you need to check why `@mail.recipients` evaluates to `nil`

Comment: Could you inspect your @mail in your partial view? You would need to pass the array correctly to your partial i.e `render :partial => "foobars", :locals => {:object => @mail}` and inside your partial `object.recipients.first`

Comment: seems to be coming through ok, i've updated the question, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should have somthing like this :

```
class Mail < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :recipients
  ....
end

class Recipient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :mail
  ....
end
```

And before calling mail.recipients.first, make sure you already defined to the 'mail' some 'recipients'.

Comment: Sorry (and thanks for responding!) but recipients is a column in the mail table.    @mail.recipients works everywhere else except for that view (including in the console if i binding.pry), can't figure it out

Comment: in this case, you should check in your database if that mail have recipients, because i think that the mail you are calling in that view dont have recipients. try <%= mail.recipients %> i think it will give you nil. before calling '.first' you either make sure that it's not nil, or you do it like this : 
<%= mail.recipients.try(:first) %>

Comment: i appreciate that, but recipients is validated, must be present